# How can I make Mathematica do, ArcTanh[x] + ArcTanh[y] = ArcTanh[x+y/1+xy]?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, trigonometry

I run this code:

```
Simplify[ArcTanh[x] + ArcTanh[y]]
```

and it keeps returning:

> `ArcTanh[x] + ArcTanh[y]`

How do I direct it to  simplify it that way ?

Comment: You have to define what is simpler for you...

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: This probably isn't true since `ArcTanh[x] + ArcTanh[y] - ArcTanh[x + y/(1 - x y)] //. {x -> 0.2, y -> 0.2}` returns a nonzero value.

Comment: You have the arctanh addition formula wrong.  It should be `ArcTanh[x] + ArcTanh[y] = ArcTanh[(x + y)/(1 + x y)]`.  Note the parentheses, plus the change of sign in the denominator.  (It's a minus sign for the inverse *tangent* function, but a plus sign for the inverse *hyperbolic tangent* function.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A little bit of trickery:

```
ArcTanh[x] + ArcTanh[y] // Tanh // TrigExpand // FullSimplify // ArcTanh

   (* ArcTanh[(x + y)/(1 + x y)] *)
```

**Note the parentheses.**

Comment: `TrigToExp` in place of `TrigExpand` works as well. The order of the last two commands also seems not to matter.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about `TrigToExp[]` is that the underlying algebraic function is not returned at once, which makes `FullSimplify[]` do more work.

Answer (score 6):

Probably, `MathematicalFunctionData["ArcTanh"]` knows about this.

First let's see what categories of things are known:

`MathematicalFunctionData["ArcTanh", "Properties"]`

ah well, let's just list them all (this will take a while to download the first time around)

```
all = DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[MathematicalFunctionData["ArcTanh", #] & /@ 
 MathematicalFunctionData["ArcTanh", "Properties"]];
```

now let's look whether that fact about `ArcTanh[_] + ArcTanh[_]` is in there

```
facts = Cases[all,
  Function[{_, _}, 
   e_ /; Not@FreeQ[e, Inactivate[ArcTanh[_] + ArcTanh[_]]]]
  ];
```

maybe some of these help. Let's Activate them.

```
activefacts = Through[facts[x, y]] // Activate
```

drop some conditions

```
activefacts = Assuming[x \[Element] Reals && y \[Element] Reals, FullSimplify@activefacts];
```

Now

```
activefacts /. {x -> ..., y -> ...}
```

should be a list of `True`, `Undefined` or `Indeterminate == ...` for any real `x` and `y`.

(However, it seems to break here for exactly one of them being 1, the other not, `activefacts /. {x -> 1, y -> 0.9}` is `{False, Undefined, False}`)

---

I think this is a method worth knowing in general.

For example, use

```
all = MathematicalFunctionData["Sinh", #] & /@ 
   MathematicalFunctionData["Sinh", "Properties"];
all = Flatten@all;
Cases[all,
 Function[{_, _}, e_ /; Not@FreeQ[e, Inactivate@Sinh[_ + _]]]
 ]
```

to learn everything `MathematicalFunctionData` knows about $\sinh(x + y)$.

Comment: See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101833/6804 for more on MathematicalFunctionData

Answer (score 5):

This is just not true for all `(x,y)`:

```
(ArcTanh[x] + ArcTanh[y] - ArcTanh[x + y/(1 - x y)]) /. x -> 0.23 /.y -> .323
```

> -0.0916564

or

```
(ArcTanh[x] + ArcTanh[y] - ArcTanh[(x + y)/(1 - x y)]) /.x -> 0.23 /. y -> .323
```

> -0.11988

```
Solve[ArcTanh[x] + ArcTanh[y] == ArcTanh[x + y/(1 - x)], {x, y}]
```

> {{x -> 0}, {y -> 0}, {y -> -1 - x + x^2}}

Comment: The formula originally used by the OP is wrong, but there is a similar one that is true.  See my comment on the original question.

Answer (score 4):

You should define a replacement rule somehow. You can store that rule in a variable and apply it locally.

```
rule = ArcTanh[x_] + ArcTanh[y_] :> ArcTanh[x + y/(1 - x)];

(* only first two terms are merged *)
ArcTanh[x] + ArcTanh[y] + ArcTanh[z] /. rule
```

> `ArcTanh[x + y/(1 - x)] + ArcTanh[z]`

```
(* merging until rule no longer applies *)
ArcTanh[x] + ArcTanh[y] + ArcTanh[z] //. rule
```

> `ArcTanh[x + y/(1 - x) + z/(1 - x - y/(1 - x))]`

Or you can associate the rule with `ArcTanh` directly. However, that is a `System` symbol and `System` symbols are (without exception I think) `Protected`, so do `Unprotect` first.

```
Unprotect[ArcTanh];
ArcTanh /: ArcTanh[x_] + ArcTanh[y_] := ArcTanh[x + y/(1 - x y)]
Protect[ArcTanh];
```

If you do this, `ArcTanh` behaves as desired and defined on its own, every time.

Answer (score 1):

You can visit the documentation center of Mathematica for trigonometric expressions at this address `tutorial/TrigonometricExpressions` for more info.

In case you need its algebraic simplification you can use this code:

```
TrigToExp[ArcTanh[x] + ArcTanh[y]]
```

Which returns this as a result:

> `-(1/2) Log[1 - x] + 1/2 Log[1 + x] - 1/2 Log[1 - y] + 1/2 Log[1 + y]`