# Conversions between hypergeometric functions

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

If I get the answer for a differential equation in terms of `HypergeometricU`, is there a way to convert that expression so that it uses `Hypergeometric1F1` instead (and `Gamma`)?

I'm thinking about this well-known (Kummer) differential equation:

`DSolve[x y''[x] + (b - x) y'[x] - a y[x] == 0, y[x], x]`

Which *Mathematica* solves,

> {{y[x] -> 
>      C[1] HypergeometricU[a, b, x] + C[2] LaguerreL[-a, -1 + b, x]}}

But which I'd like to see expressed in terms of Kummer confluent hypergeometric function `Hypergeometric1F1`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use some of the identities available from the Wolfram Functions site. Either using the built in `MathematicalFunctionData` or something like [my old `FunctionsWolfram` code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/912/34).
Using the latter, the identities you need are available as the replacement rules
[`FunctionsWolfram["07.33.27.0001.01", RuleForm]`](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.33.27.0001.01)
and
[`FunctionsWolfram["07.03.26.0002.01", RuleForm]`](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.03.26.0002.01)

Using these rules (and assuming nice things about $a$ and $b$) I get

$$c_1 U(a,b,x)+c_2 L_{-a}^{b-1}(x)=\frac{c_2 (b)_{-a} \, _1F_1(a;b;x)}{\Gamma (1-a)}+\frac{c_1 x^{1-b} \Gamma (b-1) \, _1F_1(a-b+1;2-b;x)}{\Gamma (a)}+\frac{c_1 \Gamma (1-b) \, _1F_1(a;b;x)}{\Gamma (a-b+1)}$$

Which is ugly, but you can check that it solves the original DE.

---

You can also get the same result by just using `FullSimplify` with the appropriate `ComplexityFunction`

```
cf[expr_] := 100 Count[expr,_HypergeometricU|_LaguerreL|_Hypergeometric1F1Regularized,
                       {0,Infinity}]+LeafCount[expr]
FullSimplify[DSolveValue[x y''[x]+(b-x) y'[x]-a y[x]==0,y[x],x],ComplexityFunction->cf]
```

This works completely without the need for explicit rules applied manually or in the `TransformationFunction` option. This is probably the better method!

Comment: It's nice to see you posting again, Simon. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - Thanks! It's nice to see you're still here and that the site is going well. But it's just a little procrastination... I barely use Mathematica at the moment, so don't have much reason to visit the site.

Comment: Fair enough; life moves on.  I hope things are well with you.

Comment: Thanks Simon, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly indirect method using `MeijerGReduce[]`:

```
MeijerGReduce[DSolveValue[x y''[x] + (b - x) y'[x] - a y[x] == 0, y[x], x], x] // Activate
   (C[2] Gamma[-a + b] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[a, b, x])/Gamma[1 - a] +
   C[1] HypergeometricU[a, b, x]

FunctionExpand[%]
   (C[2] Gamma[-a + b] Hypergeometric1F1[a, b, x])/(Gamma[1 - a] Gamma[b]) +
   C[1] HypergeometricU[a, b, x]
```